# Do we need an interface/contract if we cannot generalize method parameters

Tags: java, oop, interface

I want to create an interface having two methods, say `uploadFile` and `downloadFile`. While I only need the implementors to just implement these two methods, I am not sure and want to care about what arguements these methods need to take. I mean, different implementors may ask for different parameters. In that case, should I still go ahead by creating an interface by making the above methods as var-arg methods, like below

```
boolean uploadFile(Object ... parameters)
OutputStream downloadFile(Object ... parameters)
```

Or is there even a better approach than this? Is it even right to create an interface if I cannot generalize method parameters? I am only sure about the method names and say return types.

Comment: What about using generics? Dealing with the Object type is not a good design for an API..we could pass...whatever we want..that would need to be cast (ugly if/else in perspective)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a use case for generics. Consider the following arrangement of classes - here we define an abstract "parameter" type and reference this in the interface. Concrete classes work with a particular parameter set.

```
abstract class HandlerParams {    
}       

interface FileHandler<T extends HandlerParams> {
  boolean uploadFile(T parameters);
  OutputStream downloadFile(T parameters);
}
```

Example implementations:

```
class URLParams extends HandlerParams {
  // whatever...
}  

class URLFileHandler implements FileHandler<URLParams> {

  @Override
  public boolean uploadFile(URLParams parameters) {
    // ...
  }

  @Override
  public OutputStream downloadFile(URLParams parameters) {
    // ...
  }    
}
```

---

I must admit, I'm struggling to imagine scenarios where this arrangement would be that helpful. I suppose you could have something that works with file handlers, but it feels a little artificial:

```
class SomethingThatUsesFileHandlers {
  public <T extends HandlerParams> void doSomething(FileHandler<T> handler,
      T params) {
    handler.downloadFile(params);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to call with different parameter types / counts based on the implementor's type, you have two common choices:

- **Generalize parameters themselves into a separate type** - This helps you unify interfaces at the cost of static type checking
- **Forego the interface altogether** - If you need static type checking, the choice that you suggest (leaving the interface out) is valid.

Here is how you implement the first approach:

```
interface HandlerParameters {
    void setValue(String mame, Object value);
    Object getValue(String name);
    String[] getNames();
}
interface UploadDownloadHandler {
    boolean uploadFile(HandlerParameters parameters);
    OutputStream downloadFile(HandlerParameters parameters);
    HandlerParameters makeParameters();
}
```

The caller can call `makeParameters` to make an empty parameter block, populate parameter values as needed, and proceed to calling `uploadFile` or `downloadFile`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is still OK as you at least have the `uploadFile` and `downloadFile` methods defined in your contract. But it allows too many possibilities because you define `Object...` as parameters of the two methods. Maybe a better approach is to define a few concrete options for these parameters and stick to them. You can do this through several overloaded versions of these two methods e.g.

`boolean uploadFile(File)`
or
`boolean uploadFile(File...)`
or
`boolean uploadFile(File[])`

and then do the same for the

`downloadFile` method.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps You should use [generic interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)?

```
public interface XXXX< T > {
    boolean uploadFile(T... parameters)
    OutputStream downloadFile(T... parameters)
}
```